# Connect to a VNC inside a docker which is on remote server

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, docker, vnc, vnc-server

I have an Amazon Linux AMI server on AWS EC2, i have deployed "selenium docker" on it "https://github.com/elgalu/docker-selenium", the docker have a VNC running inside it.

Now how i could access this VNC?

I did some google search but did not found anything, also i tried to connect to the server ip and give the VNC display number but it gives connection refused.

I have added the VNC port as a rule on the server security rules.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution for that's case? I'm looking for that's answer as well.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38704735/how-to-watch-xvfb-session-thats-inside-a-docker-on-remote-server-from-my-local

Comment: @YonatanKiron replied on your question

Answer (score 1):

Since you have already specified the firewall rules for your VNC server the problem is most likely in VNC port listening.

first, make sure that VNC is running on localhost run

```
nc localhost 5901
```

nc = netcat (you may need to install the package)
change 5901 to your port no

you can also view the running VNC instances by :

```
vncserver -list
```

now if everything seems to be working run this command to show the port stats

```
sudo netstat -ntpl | grep 5901
```

change 5901 to your portname.

if something like

`127.0.0.1:5901` is assigned to tcp then that's the problem , we need to make sure VNC is running on

```
0.0.0.0:5901
```

which means it should accept all the traffic and not just localhost !

finally kill the vncserver by running `vncserver -kill :1` (display name), run the command :

```
vncserver -localhost no
```

P.S its an old question but may help future answer seekers.