# How to watch xvfb session that's inside a docker on remote server from my local browser?

Tags: python, selenium, docker, selenium-chromedriver, xvfb

I'm running a docker (That I built on my own), that's docker running E2E tests.
The browser is up and running but I want to have another nice to have feature, I want the ability of watching the session online.

My `docker run` command is:

```
docker run -p 4444:4444 --name ${DOCKER_TAG_NAME} 
           -e Some_ENVs 
           -v Volume:Volume 
           --privileged 
           -d "{docker-registry}" >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

I'm able to export screenshots but in some cases it's not enough and the ability of watching what is the exact state of the test would be amazing.
I tried a lot of options but I came to a dead end, Any help would be great.

- My tests are in `Python 2.7`
- My Docker base is `ubuntu:14.04`
- My environment is in AWS (If that's matter)
- The docker runs on Ubuntu servers.
- I know it a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37567285/connect-to-a-vnc-inside-a-docker-which-is-on-remote-server) but no one answered him so...

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050021/how-to-make-xvfb-display-visible

Comment: I already looked at this question,  the thing is that my problem is not watching the session from the server that the docker runs on, it's that I want to watch the session that inside the docker that inside a server. Thanks for trying to help

Comment: I think this answer should be also the solution for your problem: [can-you-run-gui-apps-in-a-docker-container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296753/can-you-run-gui-apps-in-a-docker-container/43082473#43082473)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a recent tool called [Selenoid](https://github.com/aerokube/selenoid). It is launching browsers in [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) containers (i.e. headless as you require). It has a standalone [UI](https://github.com/aerokube/selenoid-ui) capable to show live session screen via [VNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing). So you can launch multiple sessions in parallel and then look and even intercept actions happening in target browser. All this stuff perfectly works in cloud environment.

Comment: Sounds very promising, I'm giving it a shot, but for it's not getting well.. https://github.com/aerokube/selenoid/issues/102 I will update how is it going. Thanks a log!

Comment: Already answered there. Please try with these images: https://hub.docker.com/r/selenoid/vnc/

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue before with vnc, you need to know your xvfb/vnc in which port is using then open that port on you aws secuirty group once you done with that then you should be able to connect.

On my case i was starting selenium docker "https://github.com/elgalu/docker-selenium" and used this command to start the docker machine "docker run -d --name=grid -p 4444:24444 -p 5900:25900 \
  -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm -e VNC_PASSWORD=hola \
  -e SCREEN_WIDTH=1920 -e SCREEN_HEIGHT=1480 \
  elgalu/selenium"

The VNC port as per the command is "5900" so i opened that port on instance security group, and connected using VNC viewer on port 5900